# Reactive Messaging: Emit events when needed (using Kafka)

Tags: java, apache-kafka, quarkus

I am just learning Quarkus and Reactive Messaging. I am trying to message between two components. The examples I have found have demonstrated streams that have a known data set that is streamed or are repeating a payload continuously. (Such as from the Kafka Quickstart which continually streams a new random number as the price)

I need to put an event on the stream only when certain events occur in the business logic. Are there any examples?

I did find this post on StackOverflow, [Is there any function in Quarkus to send message to Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58340609/is-there-any-function-in-quarkus-to-send-message-to-kafka#). However, there are two problems:

I cannot get this form to work.

1. The emitter is always null.
2. I am attempting to do this purely using Reactive Messaging without bleeding through Kafka from the background

UPDATE:
@iabughosh

Thank you. But I am still getting an Emitter that is null injected. Here are the relevant code snippets:
    `mp.messaging.outgoing.ownercreated.connector=smallrye-kafka
 mp.messaging.outgoing.ownercreated.topic=ownercreated
mp.messaging.outgoing.ownercreated.value.serializer=io.quarkus.kafka.client.serialization.JsonbSerializer`

```
`public class Owner  {

    @Inject
    @Channel("ownercreated")
    private static Emitter<Owner> ownerCreatedChannel;

    public void persist() {
        Owner.ownerCreatedChannel.send(this);
    }
}`
```

I've injected as instance var, too.

UPDATE #2 at request of @iabughosh - Thank you for your help!

```
package org.boosey;

import io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.annotations.Channel;
import io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.annotations.Emitter;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@ApplicationScoped
public class Owner {
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Owner.class.getName());

    @Inject
    @Channel("ownercreated")
    private Emitter<Owner> ownerCreatedChannel;

    public String name;
    public String email;

    public void persist() {
        logger.info("IN PERSIST");

        ownerCreatedChannel.send(this);

        logger.info("SENT NEW OWNER");
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
mp.messaging.outgoing.ownercreated.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.outgoing.ownercreated.topic=ownercreated
mp.messaging.outgoing.ownercreated.value.serializer=io.quarkus.kafka.client.serialization.JsonbSerializer
```

The Owner.persist method is being called from a Quarkus REST Resource class. I have verified that a properly instantiated Owner object is received in Owner.persist.

```
@Path("/owner")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApplicationScoped
public class OwnerResource {

    @POST
    public Response create(Owner owner) {
        owner.persist();
        return Response.status(201).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add @javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped to your class and remove static from your Emitter field. You don't need to use static with CDI dependency injection.

Comment: I removed the static and added the @ApplicationScoped. The emitter, ownerCreatedChannel, still has a null value. Would it make a difference that my message is a JSON object? I have the serializers according to the guides.

Comment: I assume this is the correct Emitter import: io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.annotations.Emitter;

Comment: Please share your full class code.

Comment: And how do you call Owner method persist? I am assuming you are injecting Owner as CDI bean.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, your update made no difference. Neither did any of another 2 dozen solutions I've tried today including creating a brand new scaffold at Quarkus.io and using Gradle as the build system (which was suggested as a problem in one discussion). I think at this point, I am going to log an issue on the Quarkus github account and upload a minimal project to reproduce.

Comment: Can you share the new project that you were trying on GitHub? I will check it out better if you do

Comment: Thank you for continuing to help with this. I have created a example project with instructions to run it in the readme. The link is: https://github.com/boosey/quarkus-channel-problem-example

Comment: As I mentioned in my updated answer. You are trying to inject beans while you are not in CDI context. I've fixed your code and added a consumer too. I couldn't update your repository due to permissions issue so I've uploaded it here : https://github.com/iabughosh/channel-problem .

Comment: Your solution did work. I have no idea why I couldn't get it to work when I tried it earlier. This was so much help! Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an `outgoing` topic configured correctly in application.properties file, all you need to do is to inject Emitter like this :

```
@Inject
@Channel("your-channel")
Emitter<String> outgoingChannel;
```

and in your function you can call :

```
outgoingChannel.send(msg);
```

where your-channel will look like this in config file :

```
mp.messaging.outgoing.your-channel.topic=kafka-topic
```

Update :
Move Emitter (Along with annotations) code to OwnerResource, it should work smoothly. Also you can remove @ApplicationScoped from Owner if you moved that code. What happening here is Owner object is not created by CDI, that's why it is not injecting any other objects.
Regards.